# using c# how can I extract information about the hard drives present on the local machine

Tags: c#, hard-drive

I'm looking to get data such as Size/Capacity, Serial No, Model No, Heads Sectors, Manufacturer and possibly SMART data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use WMI Calls to access info about the hard disks.

//Requires using System.Management; & System.Management.dll Reference

```
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\""); 
disk.Get(); 
Console.WriteLine("Logical Disk Size = " + disk["Size"] + " bytes"); 
Console.WriteLine("Logical Disk FreeSpace = " + disk["FreeSpace"] + "bytes");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace:

```
System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher ms =
    new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in ms.Get())
{
    System.Console.Write(mo["Model");
}
```

For details on the members of the Win32_DiskDrive class, check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use WMI to get the required information. Take at look at the documentation for [Win32___DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx) in MSDN, which contains a variety of standard drive properties. You can also try using the MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData WMI class, which I can't find any docs for at the moment, but should have all of the SMART data that you're looking for. Here's some basic sample code to enumerate all drives and get their properties:

```
ManagementClass driveClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
ManagementObjectCollection drives = driveClass.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject drive in drives) 
{ 
    foreach (PropertyData property in drive.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Property: {0}, Value: {1}", property.Name, property.Value);        
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: any idea if you can check read/write speeds with a test file using WMI ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WMI](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive334.html) to get most of the information you want, and there's an introduction to WMI [here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial73_An-introduction-in-retrieving-WMI-in-Csharp.html).