# How to lookup Hard Drive model with C#?

Tags: c#

In part of a program I am writing, I'm trying to pull device information about specified local hard drives.  I've been able to create a few value returning methods using the DriveInfo class like this:

```
//Gets drive format
    public string GetDriveFormat(string driveName)
    {
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == driveName)
            {
                return drive.DriveFormat;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
//Example of use
   MessageBox.Show(GetDriveFormat("C:\\"));
```

The problem I'm running into now is that there doesn't seem to be a Model property to the DriveInfo class.  I've looked all over but am unable to find a way to construct a value returning method that will return the model of a drive like what is viewable in device manager.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: this link will help gives you a good code example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6077/How-to-Retrieve-the-REAL-Hard-Drive-Serial-Number also this one is even better http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial233_Getting-Disk-Drive-Information-using-WMI-and-Csharp.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [using c# how can I extract information about the hard drives present on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232979/using-c-sharp-how-can-i-extract-information-about-the-hard-drives-present-on-the)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot get the Drive's Manufacturer and Model using the `DriveInfo` class.

You'll have to resort back to WMI:

```
WqlObjectQuery q = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
using (ManagementObjectSearcher res = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q)) {
foreach (ManagementObject o in res.Get()) {
Console.WriteLine("Caption = " + o["Caption"]);
Console.WriteLine("DeviceID = " + o["DeviceID"]);
Console.WriteLine("Decsription = " + o["Description"]);
Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer = " + o["Manufacturer"]);
Console.WriteLine("MediaType = " + o["MediaType"]);
Console.WriteLine("Model = " + o["Model"]);
Console.WriteLine("Name = " + o["Name"]);
// only in Vista, 2008 & etc: //Console.WriteLine("SerialNumber = " + o["SerialNumber"]);
} }
```

Not sure if you need to consider mounted drives as well:

```
foreach(ManagementObject volume in new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Volume" ).Get())
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that ManagementObjectSearcher implements IDisposable.  So maybe this should be wrapped in a using statement?  I am assuming that this will also dispose of the ManagementObjects or do these have to be disposed of individually?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if you can get that info without using lower level api's. This post should help you achieve your goal.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Quick summary of the link:

- Add a reference to the `System.Management` library

Then you can use:

```
var disks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
foreach (ManagementObject disk in disks.Get())
{
   Console.WriteLine(disk["Model"].ToString());
   Console.WriteLine("\tSerial: " + disk["SerialNumber"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a lower-level API to get this information, and even then it still might not be accurate.*  The internal details of the hard drives is exposed in the Win32 APIs, which you can still access in C# through WMI.

*: Note that this is still limited to the hardware information as Windows is able to see it.  In some conditions, it won't or can't be accurate (e.g. with a RAID array, where Windows sees N drives as a single drive).

Answer (score 0):

here is something that can also work for you feel free to tweak it as you please

```
String drive = "c";
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\"" + drive + ":\"");
disk.Get();
Console.WriteLine(disk["VolumeName"]);
foreach (var props in disk.Properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(props.Name + " " + props.Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```